# How do I stack Bootstrap columns differently?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a noob with Bootstrap, though it's immensely cool and helpful! I have a question.

I'm trying to make some buttons that go like this on a wide screen:

```
Button 1    Button 3
Button 2    Button 4
```

But this on a small screen:

```
Button 1
Button 2
Button 3
Button 4
```

Is it possible to stack them like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/106650

**EDIT..**

To change the stack order, you'll want to nest the cols like this..

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">  
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I updated the demo: http://bootply.com/106650

Comment: Thanks for this - however, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. The buttons are still going from side-to-side. I'd like Button 1 stacked on top of Button 2 and then Button 3 on top of Button 4. Right now they're going from right to left and then top to bottom; I'm trying to get them to go top to bottom and then left to right.

Answer (score 0):

This is the base that will help you to achieve what you want to do.  You may need some tweaks based on your specific screen sizes.  You may also find more details at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this, however, I've already got something similar. The problem is this does:

    Button 1    Button 2
    Button 3    Button 4

The buttons go side-to-side when laid out beside each other, rather than top to bottom.